# How to loop html table rows using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here's my PHP

```
case "Add":
     if(isset($_POST['Add'])){
          $Addquery = "INSERT INTO tb_empgrocery (empgrocID, coopmemID , date_ordered, item_no, qty_ordered, unit_price, amount, date_delivered, qty_delivered, order_status, released_by) VALUES ('".$_POST['empgrocID']."', '".$_SESSION['coopmemID']."', (NOW()), '".$_POST['itemNo']."', '".$_POST['orderqty']."', '".$_POST['unit_price']."', '".$_POST['amount']."', '".$_POST['date_delivered']."', '".$_POST['qty_delivered']."','".$_POST['order_status']."','".$_POST['released_by']."')";
          mysql_query($Addquery, $con);
     }
break;
```

This is my loop function

```
function saveID(itemID){
     var check = false;
     $('#cLoanOut2 > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
          if ($(this).attr('id') === itemID){
               check = true;
               return false;
          }
     });
               return check;
}
```

Here's my jquery ajax

```
$('#OKBtn2').click(function(){
     $('#myModal2').modal('hide');
     var itemid = $('#main-form2 .active').attr('id'),
     qty = $('#main-form2 #'+itemid+' td:eq(2)').text(),
     amount = $('#main-form2 #'+itemid+' td:eq(4)').text();
     var itemID = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
     $('#itemID').val(itemID);
     bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?","No","Yes",function(r){
          if(r) {
               saveID(itemID);
               var itemno = $('#itemNo').val();
//             var currqty = $('#orderqty').val();
               var unit_price = $('#unitPrice').val();
//             var Amount = $('#amount').val();
               $.ajax({  
                    url : url,
                    type : "POST",
                    async : false,
                    data : {
                         Add: 1,
                         itemNo: itemno,
                         orderqty: qty,
                         unit_price: unit_price,
                         amount: amount,
                         todo:"Add"
                     },
                     success:function(result){
                          bootbox.alert('Ordered',function(){
                               });
                          updateTable();
                     }
                });   
           } else {

           }
     });
});
```

Here's I want to make. I have a form and when i click okbtn2 a bootbox confirm will show and if i click yes it will loop all the rows so that all items that I've ordered will be added on my database. Add works on the database but it doesn't add the next row so I have to work on my loop inside the OKBtn2 function

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where's the PHP part?

Comment: Your entire loop could be replaced by `return $('#' + itemID).length > 0`

Comment: Try looping like -> `$('#cLoanOut2 tbody  tr').each` . Remove `>`

Comment: @Epodax There's my PHP part

Comment: Little security advices:
* Check that ALL the fields are set (and not just the 'Add' field)
* Use PDO to prepare the query, this is highly vulnerable to SQL Injection

Comment: I don't know if I correctly placed my codes by calling that loop inside the bootbox confirm. But my loop function works.. I just don't know where to call that loop.. I need this- (After clicking OKBtn2, this will show - (are you sure? no, yes) and after clicking yes it will loop all rows in the form and add rows all the items in my cartlist to the database)

Comment: @AlekosFilini I just need the item's description. Add works on the database but it doesn't add the next row so I have to work on my loop inside the OKBtn2 function

Comment: You need to push every information into array and loop this array, hope this help.

Comment: @MartijnPieters please undelete my answer